# Executing multiple Bash commands after OR

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, scripting

I'm writing a Bash script to install some software; Is there a way to create a one liner that executes multiple commands after an OR? Basically, what I want to do for error checking is is this:

```
sudo apt-get install fortune || (echo "Installation failed" ; exit)
echo "Installation successful"
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't exit the script when the installation fails, and still outputs "Installation successful" as well. Any ideas on how to edit this method to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses create a subshell, which is what the `exit` commands exits. You want a command *group*, defined with braces.

```
sudo apt-get install fortune || { echo "Installation failed" >&2; exit 1; }
```

(Note the last semicolon and the spaces around the braces; all are important.)

To keep things more readable, typically you define a function to act as the single command following `||`:

```
abort () { echo "Installation of $1 failed" >&2; exit 1; }

sudo apt-get install fortune || abort fortune
```

Comment: Two additional suggestions: send the error message to stderr instead of stdout (that's what it's for), and exit with a nonzero status (to indicate there was an error).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! If I wanted to get the exit code of the function that just executed, how would I send that to the `abort` function you just wrote? Would I be able to assign $? to a variable in it and then echo that?

Comment: @AndreasKralj, consider `die() { retval=$?; echo "$*" >&2; exit $(( retval ? retval : 1 )); }` -- thus, `foo || die "foo failed"` will pass through the exit status of `foo`, whereas `die whatever` with a `$?` of 0 will use 1.

Comment: This all become a lot easier if you stop trying to be excessively verbose.  `apt-get` prints a perfectly reasonable error message, and you don't add much information by writing "Installation of $1 failed".  If you simply omit that, you can just write `sudo apt-get install fotrune || exit`, and the value returned by sudo will be returned by the script.  (`exit` with you argument is the same as `exit $?`, and if you want to be explicit just write `exit $?`).

Comment: @William Pursell Yes I understand that, but I want to suppress all output to the terminal except for my error messages, so that instead of the terminal dumping a bunch of information, it will only output whether the command has succeeded or not. I'm saving the output to a log file that the user can check upon an error. Simply exiting will be unhelpful to the user because they won't know what went wrong. I'm using this in conjunction with a loading function I wrote that will indicate that the command is in progress by displaying a "spinner" so that the user knows the command is still running.